Does exist any way to test a subclass that extends another class isolated from parent class?
I am working on java. I have this class ConfigServer that extends the class GeneralServer, to clarify I mean: public class ConfigServer extends GeneralServer. What I want to do is to create an instance of ConfigServer but isolated from the superclass functionality. Is possible programmatically to make something like this in a way that the solution wouldn't affect the current architecture and inheritance?
I need to make this isolation because if I use the actual GeneralServer class then I need to configure the whole environment that will hosts a database which will communicate with the GeneralServer but I need to avoid this time consuming process. So as I can think the only manner that I could be something like this, is to create a new class for example ConfigServerTestImpl but I think that is not the appropriate way to implement integration test for between two classes.

Consider using composition instead of inheritance.

Make an interface that defines what GeneralServer does, and have GeneralServer implement that. Make an interface to describe what ConfigServer does in addition, and have ConfigServer implement both. You can make a mock that also implements both interfaces, and if it's a injected dependency, pass the mock in for the test case.

If your ConfigServer extends GeneralServer then parent class functionality will definitely be available in child class, you can override them as per use case and call only necessary methods(using super()) or override methods to provide new functionality as and when required.
Second way is to use Strategy design pattern(has a relationship) where in you can simply provide a reference to parent class in child class and add functionality as per usage and at the same time refer parent class functionality when required.
